# How to iterate from JSON datatype in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a form on select from dropdown the request goes to the controller and returns the following in 
JSON formate

```
[{id: 2, slug: "manager", name: "Assistant Manager", created_at: "2019-12-10 09:20:45",…}]
0: {id: 2, slug: "manager", name: "Assistant Manager", created_at: "2019-12-10 09:20:45",…}
created_at: "2019-12-10 09:20:45"
id: 2
name: "Assistant Manager"
permissions: [{id: 2, slug: "edit-users", name: "Edit Users", created_at: "2019-12-10 09:21:01",…}]
0: {id: 2, slug: "edit-users", name: "Edit Users", created_at: "2019-12-10 09:21:01",…}
slug: "manager"
updated_at: "2019-12-10 09:20:45"
```

now i want to iterate from `permissions` and show `name` in another drop-down with multiple selection buit i don't know how to iterate from this JSON i tried the following script but doesn't work

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#roles").on('change', function () {
            var query = $(this).val();
            // alert(query);

            if (query != '') {

                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{route('get-roles-ajax-call')}}",
                    method: "POST",
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data: {"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}", query: query},
                    success: function (data) {
                        var values = $.parseJSON(data)
                        $(values).each(function(i,val){
                            $.each(val,function(key,val)
                            {
                                console.log(key + " : " + val);
                            });

                        });


                    }
                });
            }
             return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: The very first thing you should do is `console.log(data)` and check the result. AFAIK jQuery already parses the reply, so provided the server does return proper JSON, you should be able to directly access something like `data.permissions`

Answer (score 1):

When setting this line `dataType: 'JSON'` you are already telling the `$.ajax` function to return JSON.
Quoted from [jQuery documentation of `$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object.

So there is no need to parse the data once you've received it. Is is already JSON.

Now loop through every object in the data to search for the `permissions` property. If the object has the permissions property and the value of that is an array that is not empty then loop over each object in the `permissions` array and look for the the `name` property on each permission.

```
$.each(data, function(i, entry) {
    var permissions = entry.hasOwnProperty('permissions');
    if (permissions && permissions.length) {
        $.each(entry.permissions, function(j, permission) {
             console.log(permission.name);
        });
    }
});
```

Though I would suggest that you modify the, or create a new, server response so that all this filter work is done server side and you only have to call the server to get the data you need.